# forEach displays only last item from the list

Tags: javascript

I would like to display some of my data for each item from my list. The problem is that the function is displaying only information about the last item.
Here's how the function looks:

```
drivers.forEach(addLink);

function addLink(driver, index) {
  const nameList = document.getElementById('nameList');
  const driverImg = document.getElementById('driverImg');
  nameList.href = `?driver=${index}`;
  nameList.textContent = driver.name;
  driverImg.src = driver.image;
  driverImg.height = "45";
  list.appendChild(nameList);
  list.appendChild(driverImg);
 }
```

It was working when it was creating elements (const nameList = document.createElement('a'); , but I wanted to change that to getElementById

html looks like this:

```
    <nav id="list">
       <a id="nameList"></a>
       <img id="driverImg">
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your function is called `addLink` but it gets an **existing** element (with `getElementById`) and **changes it**. When you change it multiple times, you end up with the last set of changes you made to it.

If you want to create a link you need [`createElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement).

Answer (score 0):

Since you actually want to add Elements you need to create them like you did before, now you are just getting the same element that allready is on the document and changing it's values (overwrititing the changes from the previous iteration in every iteration)